# Storing arrays in cache

Tags: c, arrays, performance, caching, linked-list

I was reviewing an interview question and comparing notes with a friend, and we have different ideas on one with respect to CPU caching.

Consider a large set of data, such as a large array of `double`, ie:

```
double data[1024];
```

Consider using a dynamically allocated on-the-fly linked list to store the same number of elements. The question asked for a description of a number of trade-offs:

1. Which allows for quicker random access: we both agreed the array was quicker, since you didn't have to traverse the list in a linear fashion (`O(n)`), just provide an index (`O(1)`).
2. Which is quicker for comparing two lists of the same length: we both decided that if it was just primitive data types, the array would allow for a `memcmp()`, while the linked list required element-wise comparison plus dereferencing overhead.
3. Which allowed for more efficient caching if you were accessing the same element several times?

In point `3`, this is where our opinions differed. I contended that that the CPU is going to try and cache the entire array, and if the array is obscenely large, it can't be stored in cache, and therefore there will be no caching benefit. With the linked list, individual elements can be cached. Therefore, linked lists lend themselves to cache "hits" more than static arrays do when dealing with a very large number of elements.

To the question: Which of the two is better for cache "hits", and can modern systems cache part of an array, or do they need the whole array or it won't try? Any sort of references to technical documents or standards I could also use to provide a definitive answer would help a lot.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CPU doesn't know about your data structures.  It caches more-or-less raw blocks of memory.  Therefore, if you suppose you can access the same one element multiple times without traversing the list each time, then neither linked list nor array has a caching advantage over the other.

HOWEVER, arrays have a big advantage over dynamically-allocated linked lists for accessing multiple elements in sequence.  Because CPU caches operate on blocks of memory rather larger than one `double`, when one array element is in the cache, it is likely that several others that reside at adjacent addresses are in the cache, too.  Thus one (slow) read from main memory gives access to (fast) cached access to multiple adjacent array elements.  The same is not true of linked lists, as nodes may be allocated anywhere in memory, and even a single node has at minimum the overhead of a `next` pointer to dilute the number of data elements that may be cached at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Caches don't know about arrays, they just see memory accesses and store a little bit of the memory near that address. Once you've accessed something at an address it should stick around in the cache a while, regardless of whether that address belongs to an array or a linked list. But the cache controllers don't really know what's being accessed.

When you traverse an array, the cache system may pre-fetch the next bit of an array. This is usually heuristically driven (maybe with some compiler hints).

Some hardware and toolchains offer intrinsics that let you control cache residency (through pre-fetches, explicit flushes and so forth). Normally you don't need this kind of control, but for things like DSP code, resource-constrained game consoles and OS-level stuff that needs to worry about cache coherency it's pretty common to see people use this functionality.

Comment: I don't really know what he wanted to hear, but If I were your interviewer, I would have probably expected you to say "there is no valid general answer to this question". It depends on machine architecture and dynamic memory implementation. Ideally (large caches and suitable allocation chunks in the dynamic memory implementation), there will be no measurable difference. Storing just floats in linked lists however, is almost always a serious waste of ressources and doesn't make sense in most cases. Don't make things more complicated than necessary.